# Is there a way to describe the chosen jQuery Query Builder filters as plain text?

Tags: jquery-query-builder

[image]

Base on this screenshot, can we have a description like:

```
Price less 10.25
AND
(Category equals Movies OR Category equals Books)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  You need to write a a plugin to do so.

A great example is the existing sql-support plugins on github at: https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/blob/dev/src/plugins/sql-support/plugin.js

Lines 16 through 227 are configuration and helpers to map the rules operators and conditions to SQL operators and conditions.  Lines 237 and beyond are extensions to the QueryBuilder.  Those methods transform the Query Builder's data to a nice SQL format.

You need to do something like this for yourself.